# Where can I rent a car in Toronto without a credit card?

Tags: car-rentals, toronto

I already know that car rental agencies at Pearson Airport allow car rentals without a credit card, if you have a return ticket with your name. Thus I am not asking about airport rentals.

I am happy to pay by cash (a cash deposit), or my VISA debit card.

**Update -** I called Practicar which does accept cash, but requires a $1000 Canadian dollars deposit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rent A Wreck info page](https://www.rentawreck.com/info.htm) is rather helpful and includes these

> Usually, Rent-A-Wreck requires renters to be at least 18 years old, but some locations may require a minimum age of 25 years. For consumers under 25, a credit card is usually required for payment and the rental rate may be higher. Please contact the individual Rent-A-Wreck car rental location for their specific age policies.
>
> Many, but not all, Rent-A-Wreck locations will rent to cash customers. Most locations will require that cash customers fill out a cash qualification questionnaire at the rental location during normal business hours so that it may be verified. A cash deposit will be required if a credit card is not presented for payment. If you are interested in renting a car using cash, please contact the individual location for their specific prices and policies.
>
> Debit cards or 'check cards' carrying the logo of a major bank processor like VISA or MasterCard that are linked to checking accounts are also accepted as a form of payment at most Rent-A-Wreck locations.

In Canada they redirect to http://practicar.ca which have many, many Toronto locations. Good luck!